# Allow the snippet editor's areas for code and results to be resized by the user

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

I've answered a question on Stack Overflow. I wanted to move one of the borders between the HTML, JavaScript, CSS, and Result panes in the snippet editor, but I couldn't move it. In other words, I want to resize the panes of the snippet editor.

Screenshot:

[image: Border between panes of a stack snippet]